# Do we need terracotta on top of ehcache for clustering?

Tags: java, ehcache, terracotta

I am doing to a proof of concept using ehcache as the cache provider.

Read somewhere saying we need terracotta server running, ALONG WITH ehcache to provide clustering.

Does ehcache alone provide clustering service or we need terracotta also?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't require clustering, but replication would suffice, ehcache comes with RMI replication bundled and has jgroups as well as JMS replication available:

see http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/get-started/cache-topologies.html#replicated-caching

Comment: Hi Alex, i have tried both RMI and JGroups clustering. both seems to be working fine. But do you have any idea which one suits my case best!

Comment: Hard to tell, not really knowing all details... JGroups is using multicast, make sure this is something you'll be able to depend on when going into production.

Comment: @AlexSnaps what could be the practical difference (in terms of caching) between clustering and replication??

Answer (score 4):

If you want the cache (or the caches) to be available from different JVMs you will need Terracotta; ehCache alone cannot do that.

http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/get-started/about-distributed-cache.html

Of course you could also look at other solutions like Hazelcast.

http://www.hazelcast.com/

Comment: What can be the best open source solution here? I have similar reuqiremnt where i want to replicate user session.

Answer (score 4):

EhCache is not a distributed solution. So you need to use it with Terracotta to obtain the result you want. Like moodywoody said, you can use Hazelcast, but also Infinispan to obtain this result:

http://www.jboss.org/infinispan

Comment: Yes, Infinispan is distributed (peer-to-peer), based on JGroups.  Terracotta follows a hub-and-spoke design which is very different.

Comment: Hi, my requirement is to just replicate. I have 2 servers in my cache cluster and i want the date to be in sync. i dont need the cache to be distributed.

Comment: @Manik Surtani : Sure, Terracotta is a very different solution, but with EhCache, it can be used for the same purpose.

Comment: @venkataratnam: An EhCache cache is related to one JVM. So you need either to use a distributed cache for your different JVMs (Infinispan or Hazelcast), which means multiple caches (for each JVM), synchronized, or to use a clustered JVM (Oracle Coherence or Tarracotta) with one cache. And EhCache works very well with Terracotta.

Comment: @Traroth. Thanks. The same would be applicable to Replicated Cache also right?

Comment: @venkataratnam: You mean Replicated Cache Service, for Coherence? I would say so...

Comment: I meant, If i want my cache to be replicated on all the nodes(puts,gets,removes..everything) of the cluster..then also i would need terracotta right?

Comment: Actually, with Terracotta, your system will roughly behave like one single JVM running on multiple machines, so you will actually have one cache attached to your Terracotta instance.

Comment: @traroth,This is my understanding.. You can make ehcache clustered using EITHER terracotta OR JGroups/JMS replication.. Please correct me if its wrong